# SQL Server Replication - One-to-Many in Same DB

Tags: sql-server, replication, transactional-replication

I'm setting up some canary tables to more effectively monitor replication latency between on-prem and Azure. I've set it up using one source table that gets updated with a timestamp every few seconds, and have added that into each publication to be delivered into individual tables at destination, one per publication.

However, only the last publication that I added the table to is staying in sync.

Is it an issue replicating one table into multiple tables within the same DB, do I need one source table per publication?

[image: Diagram]

Comment: Any errors in the [Replication Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/monitor/start-the-replication-monitor?view=sql-server-ver15) or SQL Agent Job for the publications that are failing?